# Font of label changes back to default when label's text changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used custom renderer for setting up a font.. The issue is when I change the text for the label the font style disappers..

Provided is my custom renderer code.. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyLabel), typeof (MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace FormsProj.Droid
{
public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        var label = (TextView)Control;
        Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "Raleway-Regular.ttf");
        label.Typeface = font;
    }
}
}
```

**Update #1**
This is my Code Shared Project
    using System;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace FormsProj
{
public class MyLabel:Label
 {
 }
}
```

**Code Where I'm using MyLabel**

```
var Thankyoutxt = new MyLabel {
            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
            Text = "Thank You",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            Style = Device.Styles.CaptionStyle,
            FontFamily = ColorandFont.FontName,

        };
```

On a click of the button I will change text, By that time the font changes back without custom font..

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Where are you changing the text? I'm only seeing the code for changing the font.

Comment: @JohnOdom Chaging text code is like **label.Text ="Edited";** I assumed problem lies within Renderer..

Comment: I was hoping that you would post the code on where you are changing the text. I already know how to change the text :P. It could maybe be an issue with how you are calling the renderer.

Comment: @JohnOdom Sorry :) I was just explaining that I have done nothing more than that one line..

Comment: Well how about the `MyLabelRenderer'? Can you show how you are using that?

Comment: What is ColorandFont.FontName? That is likely the source of your issue as a change of the Text value will force a redraw - the renderer code will not be re-executed though

Comment: ColorFont is just a static class where i have provide font name For iOS.. I have noticed this issue only on android.. Am I doing anything wrong in the custom renderer while redrawing??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try resetting the properties on the OnPropertyChangedEvent in the renderer as well. I have had issues with this in the past, and this has fixed it.